# Clean Master app is preventing my app from showing notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

we are facing an issue where apps like "clean master / all cleaner" are preventing our app from showing notifications and our notifications are being treated as junk, while our app is highly dependent on notifications.
this can be fixed by going to the cleaner app settings and change the configurations manually, but is there any way to prevent apps like this from having access over our notifications, and to always show our notifications ?

Comment: How do you create this notifications? Is it a service? Most of services running in background would be killed after sometime by the system to prevent battery drain.

Comment: @MarkWalczak  we are using OneSignal to send push notifications to the app. its not a foreground/background service, its just a push notification

Comment: According to the documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup  NotificationExtenderService is responsible for handling the notifications. Probably it is killed by the clean master.

Comment: @MarkWalczak yes it is getting killed by clean master, this is my issue and the question is: is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I don't know how to stop this with OneSignal... I can recommend Firebase Cloud Messages with data payload though, which is handled by the system tray - doesn't need any service so the notifications are always delivered.

Comment: @MarkWalczak im not quite sure but i think OneSignal does use Firebase servers for push notifications and data is being sent with payload. the push notification is getting delivered from OneSignal but blocked to show the notification in the notifications center from the cleaner app.

Comment: Did you try to extend NotificationExtenderService like this: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#section-notification-extender-service ?

Comment: @MarkWalczak yes we tried this and even set the notification priority to HIGH and still the notification is not showing. i guess our only hope is to ask the users to manually disable it, thank you Mark